# How compare SQL Server Datetime from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I've got to make a query from C# and compare with a `datetime`. Datetime is stored in my database like this:

```
2014-11-09 00:00:01
```

and I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE DATETIMEVAR = '19/11/2014 0:00:01' AND OTHERVAR = 1
```

But it's not in the same format. Is there a way to convert from `System.DateTime` in C# to dates in SQL Server, or a way to cast from SQL Server the datetime in that format?? Should I check with `like` instead of `=` in `Where` clause.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there should be any issue in passing datetime from C# to sql server. What issue are you facing ?

Comment: If you store a datetime in SQL then it has no format. Same like a DateTime in C# - it also has no format. It is not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are generating the query from a DateTime object, just do `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` to convert it to that format in your query.

Comment: Uppercase "SS" should be lower case, dude!

Answer (score 5):

The **best** way would be to have a **parametrized** query in C#, and then set your date time parameter **as a datetime** (instead of relying on converting dates back and forth to and from strings).

So you should have something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE DATETIMEVAR = @DateTimeValue AND OTHERVAR = 1
```

and then define that `@DateTimeValue` parameter **as datetime** and set it as datetime

That approach:

- prevents any **SQL injection** vulnerability
- avoid any string/formatting issues - it compares a `DATETIME` to a `System.DateTime` in their *native* format